# How can I disable all elements inside a fieldset in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, fieldset

I have 2 `<fieldset>`s on my page, but one of them should have all of it elements disabled depending on some user's choice.

The fieldsets contain text inputs, selects, and links. Is there a way to disable all of them instead of disabling them one by one?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

What about using the children selector?

```
$("#myfieldeset").children().attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

You can also filter the children selection:

```
$("#myfieldeset").children("a,input");
```

Comment: Thanks!! I used something similar but your explanation will be useful for other thing I have t do! :-)

Comment: as of jquery 1.6, [it's recommended to use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()` to set the value of properties](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop2), this can be like: `.prop("disabled", true)`

Comment: I noticed that if the parent fieldset element is disabled, then all child elements will be disabled, even if there is fieldset element which is enabled. Is this a bug of feature?

Answer (score 12):

**You can set the `disabled` attribute of `fieldset`.**

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset):

> If this Boolean attribute is set, the form controls that are its descendants, except descendants of its first optional  element, are disabled, i.e., not editable. They won't receive any browsing events, like mouse clicks or focus-related ones. Often browsers display such controls as gray.

---

**HTML**: `<fieldset disabled> ... </fieldset>`

**JQuery**: `$('#myfieldset').prop('disabled', true);`

**JS**: `document.getElementById('#myFieldset').disabled = true;`

---

**IE note**:

**This does not work quite right on Internet Explorer due to a couple bugs**, but works well just about everywhere else (including *Edge*).

In short, Text and File inputs don't properly disable, and the user can still interact with them.

If this is a deal breaker, you need to go into the  and put the `disabled` attribute on the `<fieldset>`'s descendant form controls as described in other answers here.

---

**Browser support info**: http://caniuse.com/#feat=fieldset-disabled

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you set a class="disableMe" on the fieldset you want to disable any input elements then the following code should do what you need:

```
$('fieldset.disableMe :input').attr('disabled', true)
```

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you just use:

`$("#myfieldeset").attr("disabled", "disabled");`

It worked for me. It disabled nicely all the children inputs.

**EDIT:** note thas the disabled attribute can be applied to fieldset element only in HTML5 (see merryprankster comment). Strangely enough, it does work with other browser than just Firefox and Opera, such as Chrome and Internet Explorer (tested IE7 and IE8).

Comment: No. The disabled attribute dates back to html 4. Source: [disabled attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_disabled.asp)

Comment: <fieldset> is not <input>. Your link is about <input> elements; <fieldset>s do not have `disabled` attribute prior HTML5 (and support seems to be very limited). [Source](http://w3schools.com/HTML5/att_fieldset_disabled.asp)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that. I'll do some testing with other browser, just to see if it the approach would work with older ones

Comment: Working: firefox 16, chrome 22, IE7, IE8. 
Not working: safari 5, firefox 3.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what others posted:

Use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()`:

```
$('#myfieldset').prop('disabled',true)
```

It is more correct with regard to the DOM.

And it does not seem to work well with validation. Both firefox and chrome won't let me submit the form With unfilled 'required' inputs in the disabled fieldset, but don't give any instructions on how to complete the form either.

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason you can't add an ID to the fieldset (which is usually preferred), you can always do this to hide all it's children elements:

```
$('fieldset:first > *').attr('disabled','disabled');
```