# Disable Fieldset in JqueryMobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

How do I disable a fieldset in Jquery Mobile i.e. the click event on the input should not fire and the UI updated for the children to a disabled state

HTML

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" id="options">
    <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="optiona" value="a"  checked="checked">
    <label for="optiona" id="labela">Ondo</label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="optionb" value="b">
    <label for="optionb">Lagos</label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="optionc" value="c">
    <label for="optionc">Abuja</label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="optiond" value="d">
    <label for="optiond">Kogi</label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="optione" value="e">
    <label for="optione">Niger</label>
```

I have tried the following

```
$("#options").children().attr("disabled", "disabled");
$("#options").children().prop("disabled", true);
```

But this does not disable all the children in the fieldset.

Comment: have a look here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/781584/how-can-i-disable-all-elements-inside-a-fieldset-in-jquery

Comment: dis a jquerymobile page and I am already doing something similar but it is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/nMR85/1525/

**code**

```
$("#options input[type='radio']").checkboxradio('disable');
```

**docs**

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/forms/radiobuttons/methods.html

Comment: dis meets my needs perfectly. Thanks